# What is the IPV4 class ?

Tags: ipv4

I'm trying to identify the classes of IPV4 IP's. I convert the first octet or block into binary and then i follow the algorithm here in the photo. My problem is when the IP starts with 7 for example then its binary is 111 and it doesn't match any of classes and another thing when i turn 47 for instance to binary (101111) then it should belong to class B but instead its class is A and i don't know why? [image]

Comment: `when the IP starts with 7` - i suppose like in 7.2.4.5 - it actually starts with 00000111 and not with 111 ... The [Wikipedia article on classful networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network) is quite good.

Comment: The image says "32 bits" right at the top, which is divided into 4 groups with 8 bits in each. The numbers refer to the first bits in the first 8-bit group.

Comment: @JJJ I know but ...

Comment: But what? 7 is 00000111 in 8-bit binary and starts with 0, just like fvu said. 47 is 00101111 and also starts with 0.

Comment: @fvu thanks for suggestion but how do you justify those IP's which start with 47 ? does the same rule applies there too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binary number you have separated on each net doesn't mean the class definition, a class is defined by the network portion, for example the ip you mention that starts with 7 belongs to the A class:

7 = 00000111

The A class defines the first 8 bits as the network portion
The B class defines the fisrt 16 bits as the network portion
The C class defines the first 24 bits as the network portion

Check the following tables and let me know if you have more questions.
[image]
[image]